# Image flicker when using animation

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, sass

I am using a SVG image as website mascot, there is box-shadow animation but it keeps flickering all the time.

I've tried almost all the help available such as:

```
-webskit-backface-visibility: hidden

-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d
```

I've also made sure that the image is not exceeding its container, but this flickering is just not going anywhere.

My project is live so, you can directly take a look:
http://www.saintagro.com/

Comment: It's unclear which is the animation you are talking about. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).